# Kubuntu 18.04 blank screen on resume from suspend

Tags: kubuntu, 18.04, lock-screen, gnu

Hi there GNU/Linux community.

So I've been having a problem with my Kubuntu PC where after I try to resume the computer from its suspended state the screen never turns on, stays in idle mode. My powerdevil settings are 15 mins idle until screen power off, 20 minutes until suspend, and for the lock settings the screen is supposed to lock after 15 minutes.

Sometimes the lock, suspend, etc functions work as they should and other times I get that blank screen, which has meant that I've had to reboot my computer incessantly over the past couple of days.

Hoping someone knows what I'm talking about here and could offer a solution. Thanks.

p.s. if it helps any my system specs are:
Geforce GTX 460 1gb
AMD FX 6300
6gb RAM

Answer (score 2):

**Update :**

Since the previous fix isn't working, and it appears LibreOffice is causing the crash in your system, try this -

1. Start LibreOffice
2. Select `Tools`(shortcut: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and then `Options` from the drop down list
3. In the L.H.S, select `Advanced` and disable the option -

> [ * ] Use a Java runtime environment

by deselecting it

> [   ] Use a Java runtime environment

4. Use `OK` to confirm the changes
5. Restart LibreOffice for good measure

---

**(Not Working)**

I've been facing the same problem on Kubuntu 18.04 with my screen blanking out and refusing to wake up no matter what I tried. 
(this happens to me when I manually lock my screen and then try to start up after about 10 mins or so after the screen has gone blank)

Try changing the power saving option for your screen like so -

1. Access the '**Energy Saving**' option from the main menu
2. Uncheck the '**Screen Energy Saving**' option(i think this might be causing the screen to power off and stop responding)
3. Do the same for the '*On Battery*' and '*On Low Battery*' tabs as well.
4. Finally, apply the changes made so far.

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  So far turning off Screen Energy Saving has been working to solve my problem.

Comment: actually no this didn't help. It's libreoffice screwing everything up.

Comment: I agree. I'm facing this issue constantly with 16.04(fresh install) as well. Only in my case I'm not running LibreOffice much so I'm not sure if that's the cause. I did notice this happens regularly when I run multiple instances of eclipse based tools and database clients. 
Specs - _i7(8th Gen) with a 2GB Intel GPU and 16 GB RAM running Kubuntu 16.04.4_

Comment: Hmm. I tried turning off java Runtime Environment like your new edit suggests to do but I got the blank screen on resume problem again! and of course, I haven't seen the problem at all in the days between where I didn't open libreoffice... I left a bug report on bugzilla we'll see what happens.